# How to convert "indent level" to SUBTOTAL formula with a macro?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, automation

I've been given over 100 excel sheets, each with multiple thousands of entries that look like the following:

[image]

*NOTE: Just the first 3 columns are in the file. I want to either modify the third column, or add the 4th as shown above.

I need to edit these files, delete certain rows, and the total roll-up prices need to be correct. Unfortunately, column C is hardcoded with the values. **How do I convert the "Price" column to use the subtotal function as in the rightmost column? i.e. auto-generate column D given the first 3 columns.** I do not want to go through each file line by line.

I have the indent level, which should theoretically make this easy, but I've never really worked with macros before. I'm not sure how this would be accomplished with just formulas, but I suppose it could be done.

I can either modify column C or create an additional column, D.

Comment: I will ask you the same question I asked you [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1485897/how-to-convert-indent-level-to-subtotal-formula-with-a-macro): Could you please clarify the desired outcome and how you would get to it?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad And I edited the other post to do so. It seems pretty clear to me. Not sure how much clearer I can make it.

Comment: So basically if nextRow indent value >  currentRow value sum all price values until a row indent value <= currentRow value? Otherwise if currentRow indentvalue = nextRow indentvalue calculated value should be that rows price. Also providing a copyable example data set would be helpful for testing purposes.

Comment: (1) Is column 1 as you show it (N periods then N)?  (2) It does not really matter but I do not understand the advantage of `SUBTOTAL(9, Range)` over `SUM(Range)`.

Comment: (1) For row 8, I would expect the range to be C9:C18.  (2) For row 20, the formula gives the value in column 3.  This is not true for rows 2, 8, 9 and 19.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mike That's the idea of it, I'm just not sure how to execute it

Comment: @TonyDallimore Subtotal allows me to get higher level roll-ups. Sum would include both the piece parts and roll-ups in the summation. For Row 8, you are correct, I made a typo. For Row 20, there is only 1 piece part in the assembly, so yes - the roll-up would be the same as the row below it.

Comment: I cannot get Subtotal to work as you expect and the documentation says.  In all my experiments, it gives the same results as Sum; that is, it double counts sub-totals.  In your image, the formulae are text strings.  Please convert them to Excel formulae and see if they give the expected answer on your system.  I am using Office 365.

Comment: Example 1: In D20, I have `=SUBTOTAL(9,C21:C21)`  which has a value of 1,512.00 as expected. In D19, I have `=SUBTOTAL(9,C20:C22)` which has a value of 3,068.88 which is 1,512.00 more than expected.

Comment: Example 2: In D2, I have `=SUBTOTAL(9,C3:C22)` which has a value of 66,956.52.  `=SUM(C3:C7)+SUM(C10:C18)+SUM(C21:C21)` has a value of 47,172.28 which matches C2.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I actually generated column C with the formula in column D. You are seeing the result of the formula. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have produced the formulae you want (I think) but those formulae do not evaluate to the values you want.  Perhaps you can see an error I am overlooking.  Perhaps function `SUBTOTAL` is affected by a switch I do not know about.  But, first an introduction to what I have created.

I needed some test data so created a worksheet containing the important columns from your example:

[image: Test data from your example]

Column B and the column headings are not relevant.  I have carefully checked and as far as I can see columns A and C match your example.

You say you have over 100 sheets but do not say if they are all in one workbook or spread over several workbooks.  I have assumed several workbooks.  You probably only have one assembly per worksheet but, just in case, I have duplicated my copy of your assembly so I have several per worksheet.  I duplicated the worksheet so I have two per workbook.  I then created two copies of the workbook.  The result is I have three data workbooks each with two worksheets to be processed.  I have created other worksheets in a different format so I can check that worksheets not to be processed are ignored.

I did not want to copy the macros to every data workbook so I have another workbook which is macro-enabled to hold my macros.  I have all four workbooks in a single folder.  I assume this is not an issue for you.  If you cannot move all your workbooks to a single folder, you will have to describe your folder structure so I can decide how to handle it.

To match my system, you will need to create a macro-enabled workbook.  That workbook must have a worksheet named “Wshts”.

I generally spread my macro over several modules.  I describe my modules but you can place all the code in a single module if you prefer.

Module “ModGlobal” contains column and row constants plus two routines from my library which I used in the macros I wrote for you:

```
Option Explicit

' Columns and first data row of worksheet "Wshts" of this workbook
Public Const ColWshtWbk As Long = 1
Public Const ColWshtWSht As Long = 2
Public Const RowWshtDataFirst As Long = 2

' Columns and first data row of a assembly worksheet
Public Const ColPartIndent As Long = 1
Public Const ColPartAmt As Long = 3
Public Const ColPartFormula As Long = 4
Public Const RowPartDataFirst As Long = 2
Public Function ColNumToCode(ByVal ColNum As Long) As String

  ' Convert an Excel column number to the equivalent code. For example 1 to "A".

  Dim ColCode As String
  Dim PartNum As Long

  ' 3Feb12  Adapted to handle three character codes.
  ' ??????  Renamed from ColCode to create a more helpful name

  If ColNum = 0 Then
    ColNumToCode = "0"
  Else
    ColCode = ""
    Do While ColNum > 0
      PartNum = (ColNum - 1) Mod 26
      ColCode = Chr(65 + PartNum) & ColCode
      ColNum = (ColNum - PartNum - 1) \ 26
    Loop
  End If

  ColNumToCode = ColCode

End Function
Public Function PadL(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long, _
                     Optional ByVal PadChr As String = " ") As String

  ' Pad Str with leading PadChr to give a total length of PadLen
  ' If the length of Str exceeds PadLen, Str will not be truncated

  '   Sep15 Coded
  ' 20Dec15 Added code so overlength strings are not truncated
  ' 10Jun16 Added PadChr so could pad with characters other than space

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadL = Str
  Else
    PadL = Right$(String(PadLen, PadChr) & Str, PadLen)
  End If

End Function
```

The worksheet “Wshts” must contain a list of the worksheets to be processed.  Module “ModListWshts” contains this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ListWshts()

  ' Build list of workbooks and worksheets to be processed by macro GenFormulae

  Dim FileName As String
  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim PathName As String
  Dim RowWsht As Long
  Dim WBk As Workbook
  Dim WshtWsht As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WshtWsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Wshts")
  With WshtWsht
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
    .Cells(1, ColWshtWbk).Value = "Workbook"
    .Cells(1, ColWshtWSht).Value = "Worksheet"
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
  End With
  RowWsht = 2

  PathName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

  FileName = Dir$(PathName & "*.xls*", vbNormal)
  Do While FileName <> ""
    If FileName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
      'Debug.Print FileName
      Set WBk = Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileName, False, True)
      With WBk
        For InxWsht = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
          'Debug.Print "  " & .Worksheets(InxWsht).Name
          WshtWsht.Cells(RowWsht, ColWshtWbk).Value = FileName
          WshtWsht.Cells(RowWsht, ColWshtWSht).Value = .Worksheets(InxWsht).Name
          RowWsht = RowWsht + 1
        Next
        .Close
      End With
    End If
    FileName = Dir$
  Loop

  WshtWsht.Columns.AutoFit

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

This macro locates all the workbooks in the folder and creates a list of workbooks and their worksheets.  I deleted the rows for the worksheets I did not want processed to create:

[image: List of worksheets to be processed]

If you run macro `ListWshts`, you will have over 100 rows in your version on this workbook.  I decided that six was enough for a test.  Delete any rows for worksheets that are not to be processed.  There are more sophisticated methods of creating a list like this but I do not know enough about your workbooks to identify a more suitable method.

Finally, module “GenGenFormulae” contains:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GenFormulae()

  ' Workbooks and worksheets to be processed are listed in worksheet Wshts.
  ' Generate a formula for each row of each worksheet to be processed.

  Dim FileNameCrnt As String
  Dim FileNameLast As String
  Dim InxWsht As Long
  Dim LevelCrnt As Long
  Dim LevelLast As Long
  Dim OpenLevelStart(0 To 999)      ' Allow for more levels than could possibly exist
                                    ' to avoid worrying about array overflow
  Dim PathName As String
  Dim RowPartCrnt As Long
  Dim RowPartLast As Long
  Dim RowWshtCrnt As Long
  Dim RowWshtLast As Long
  Dim WBk As Workbook
  Dim WshtPart As Worksheet
  Dim WshtWsht As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WshtWsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Wshts")
  RowWshtLast = WshtWsht.Cells(Rows.Count, ColWshtWbk).End(xlUp).Row

  PathName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
  FileNameLast = ""

  For RowWshtCrnt = RowWshtDataFirst To RowWshtLast
    Application.StatusBar = "Worksheet " & RowWshtCrnt - 1 & " of " & RowWshtLast - 1
    FileNameCrnt = WshtWsht.Cells(RowWshtCrnt, ColWshtWbk).Value

    If FileNameCrnt <> FileNameLast Then
      ' New workbook
      If FileNameLast <> "" Then
        ' Have an open workbook
        WBk.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Set WBk = Nothing
      End If
      FileNameLast = FileNameCrnt
      Debug.Print "Workbook " & FileNameCrnt
      Set WBk = Workbooks.Open(PathName & FileNameCrnt)
    End If

    ' Reference worksheet within open workbook
    With WBk
      Set WshtPart = .Worksheets(WshtWsht.Cells(RowWshtCrnt, ColWshtWSht).Value)
    End With

    ' Process worksheet
    With WshtPart
      RowPartLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColPartIndent).End(xlUp).Row
      Debug.Print "  Worksheet " & .Name & " (" & RowWshtCrnt - 1 & _
                  " of " & RowWshtLast - 1 & " in total) which has " & _
                  RowPartLast - 1 & " rows."

      ' Process Row RowPartDataFirst which has no previous row.
      RowPartCrnt = RowPartDataFirst
      LevelLast = CLng(Replace(.Cells(RowPartCrnt, ColPartIndent).Value, ".", ""))
      Debug.Assert LevelLast = 0   ' First data row must be level 0

      ' Unless overridden by the next row, the formula for the
      ' current row is a copy of the amount from the current row
      .Cells(RowPartCrnt, ColPartFormula).Value = _
                                        "=" & ColNumToCode(ColPartAmt) & RowPartCrnt
      'Debug.Print "    Row " & CStr(RowPartCrnt) & ", Level " & LevelCrnt

      For RowPartCrnt = RowPartDataFirst + 1 To RowPartLast

        ' For each row create the default formula, decide if the previous
        ' row requires a non-default formula and if any earlier sub-total
        ' formulae were terminated by this row

        If RowPartCrnt Mod 100 = 0 Then
          ' Display progress every 100 rows
          Application.StatusBar = "Worksheet " & RowWshtCrnt - 1 & " of " & RowWshtLast - 1 & _
                                  ".  Row " & RowPartCrnt - 1 & " of " & RowPartLast - 1
        End If

        LevelCrnt = CLng(Replace(.Cells(RowPartCrnt, ColPartIndent).Value, ".", ""))

        ' Unless overridden by the next row, the formula for the
        ' current row is a copy of the amount from the current row
        .Cells(RowPartCrnt, ColPartFormula).Value = _
                                        "=" & ColNumToCode(ColPartAmt) & RowPartCrnt
        'Debug.Print "    Row " & RowPartCrnt & ", Level " & LevelCrnt;
        If LevelCrnt = LevelLast Then
          ' This row at same level as last.
          ' No earlier row affected by this row
          'Debug.Assert False
          'Debug.Print    ' Finish diagnostic line containing row and level
        ElseIf LevelCrnt = LevelLast + 1 Then
          ' This row is immediate child of last row.
          ' Formula for previous row is at level LevelLast
          ' with the range starting on current row
          ' Store range start until range end found
          'Debug.Assert False
          OpenLevelStart(LevelLast) = RowPartCrnt
          'Debug.Print "   Start of level " & LevelLast & " subtotal"
        ElseIf LevelLast > LevelCrnt Then
          ' This row is at a lower level than last row.
          ' Levels LevelLast-1 to LevelCrnt ended on last row.
          'Debug.Assert False
          'Debug.Print
          Do While LevelLast > LevelCrnt
            LevelLast = LevelLast - 1
            'Debug.Print Space(6) & "Level " & LevelLast & " subtotal on row " & _
                        OpenLevelStart(LevelLast) - 1 & " with range " & _
                        OpenLevelStart(LevelLast) & " to " & RowPartCrnt - 1
            .Cells(OpenLevelStart(LevelLast) - 1, ColPartFormula).Value = _
                             "=SUBTOTAL(9," & ColNumToCode(ColPartAmt) & _
                             OpenLevelStart(LevelLast) & ":" & _
                             ColNumToCode(ColPartAmt) & RowPartCrnt - 1 & ")"
          Loop
        Else
          ' No code for this combination of current and last level
          Debug.Assert False
        End If
        LevelLast = LevelCrnt
      Next RowPartCrnt
    End With
    Set WshtPart = Nothing  ' This worksheet finished
  Next RowWshtCrnt

  WBk.Close SaveChanges:=True
  Set WBk = Nothing

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Run macro `GenFormulae`.  It opens workbooks as necessary and processes every worksheet listed in worksheet “Wshts”.  It writes formulae to column D.  It does not change columns A to C so you can rerun the macro if you wish.  The macro does some limited data checking but, in general, it just stops if it does not like what it finds.  The macro uses the status bar and the Immediate Window to indicate progress.  With my six, small worksheets it only takes a few seconds.  I infer that you will fix these worksheets and then not need this macro again.  If this is a recurring task, you may need a better progress indicator.

This is one of the worksheets in formula mode after I have run `GenFormulae`:

[image: Result of macro in Formula mode]

This appears to contain the formulae you want.  However, in data mode, the worksheet is:

[image: Result of macro in Data mode]

As you can see, the values are not as you want.  As I said at the top, perhaps you can see why.